# Javascript variable value change

Tags: javascript, arrays

can someone explain to me  why the variable old is still assigned to 1 instead of 8? I thought the variable old will change to 8 because I have assigned a new value to array [0]. I thought the equal sign holds the transitivity property.

```
array= [1,2,3,4,5];  
var old=array[0];  
array[0]=8;  
console.log(old);//1
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `var old=array[0];` just sets `old` to whatever value `array[0]` has at that moment, it doesn't create any kind of ongoing link with that array element.

Comment: from JS MDN - An assignment operator assigns a value to its left operand based on the value of its right operand

Answer (score 0):

```
var old=array[0];
```

Here you're assigning the value of `array[0]` to the variable `old`

This doesn't change `array[0]`. This basically means that this is passed by value and not by reference.